# What are the kinds of drill bits can I get for this?

Tags: pcb, tools

I have this PCB drill bit I bought during my college years and lucky enough, it still works! But I was hoping that there are other kinds of bits that I can use this other than drilling holes. I was wondering if there is a bit with a small circular saw that I can attach to make small cuts to shape a casing for a pcb?

I tried googling micro drill bit but I am not sure if I am getting it correct, and I can't find a bit with a circular saw. If someone could point me to an ebay (preferred) or Amazon site, I could use that as reference to find other bits that will work on this drill.

[image]

Comment: Anything with a small enough (and also big enough) shaft to fit in the collet.

Comment: Look for Dremel tools

Comment: That drill looks like it doesn't have an adjustable chuck. The bit is pushed into a holder (a "pin vice")- which is the type of thing I've seen with milling machines. That makes it somewhat awkward to find appropriate bits like cutters. I'd measure that bit you have and see if bits from a Dremel will suit.

Comment: Not electrical engineering. -

Comment: For some tools you can get a range of "collets" (the part shown with the drill in it) with a range of center holes allowing a wider range of tools that available for a single collet.You can also get small true chucks which may fit your tool. There is a reasonable chance that your system accepts Dremel parts as they are the (or a ) market leader that others copy.

Comment: Most commonly this will have a 1/8 inch collet. Searching "uk.farnell.com" for "PCB drill bit" gives appropriate parts; carbide so not cheap. Most other suppliers will have them too.

Comment: Saw blades aren't mounted on drill bits, they're mounted on mandrels. Searching for "saw blade and mandrel" gives plenty of appropriate results.

Comment: @JeannePindar as seen in the picture, do I need to buy anything to make it work for my drill? BTW, thanks for that, I was able to find them on ebay.

Comment: You need to get a mandrel that is the right diameter for the collet you have, or better yet, get an assortment of collets that fit your drill (they'll be the same diameter on the outside but different diameters on the inside).